# Why do I not fry a GPU, when it's PCIe power is connected to a second PSU?

Tags: power-supply, gpu

I see lot's of Bitcoin/Altcoin PC mining rigs having powered their graphics cards with a second power supply. They simply connect the second PSU to the card's PCIe power connectors, while they do not ground both PSU's. Is it really the correct way in doing this? I have a little bit background in electrical engineering and I was wondering how both GND's are separated in a graphics card's design. Can someone describe me this please?

Comment: The grounds are not separated, but connected somewhere on the motherboard.

Comment: Thought about that the PSU's are grounded through motherboard and graphics card. Why do people then fry their motherboards if they power an active x1 PCIe to x16 PCI riser card with an second PSU?

Comment: The ground connection can be fried too of course if the grounds have initially a big difference. Mostly when one of the grounds is floating (laptop?). But in most cases the PSUs are likely not isolated and share the same ground somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It depends on voltage differences of the 5V power combined into the card and ESR of the entire path.**

If a 2nd 5V port is used to power high loading GPU cards, they must come from matched voltage sources <0.1%.  If not thermal rise or overcurrent from circulation currents will result in issues

A typical 850W PSU has many Molex plugs for ext powered DC peripherals.

[image: 12V]
[image: If peripherals require 2 DC plugs,]

We don't know the resistance of your cables but we can see the resistance of the supply above.

- approx 1% drop with 250W @ 5V means V^2/W=R= 100 mΩ is the load and thus the source is 1% of this.  Your wire might be 2 to 5% of this 100 mΩ's. So doubling up cables improves from the same supply.

BUT if you had 2 different PSU's with ΔV=1% and connected them in parallel with a total loop cable resistance of say 50 mΩ then 1% * 5V/50mΩ = 1A of circulation current not going to the load but going between supplies.  It may get worse as the slope is not linear with more current and a bigger difference in voltage or lower resistance cable at 10 mΩ then 500% more current.

Comment: Thanks for your response. So the whole concept of sharing PSU's seems to be a bad idea if they are unbalanced. Let's say, my PSU's are loaded differently because I use PSU1 for the motherboard and PSU2 for 3 graphics cards. ΔV=2,5% @ 500W and 12V (PCIe power) would create V^2/W=R=288mΩ resistance. Assuming that you just halved the value, the resistance between the PSUs would be 144mΩ.  2,5% * 12V/144mΩ ~ 2,1A. This would mean 24,2W additional consumption.

Comment: We once used current sharing in Servers for redundancy . THe Voltages had to be balanced to less than load regulation errors and with no load they were unstable, so a pre-load was necessary back then ca. 1999. Nowadays, SMPS have better phase margin at no load. But its still a good idea, just that they need to be matched and coming from the same source guarantees that with same cable lengths.  HP used to send a Vref to all cards so current sharing or even every voltage regulator had the same reference. So it depends if you want true redundancy or perfect current sharing.

Comment: A) Shouldn't that chart be labelled "load regulation" rather than "line regulation"? B) PCIe power connectors only use the 12 V rail, there is no 5 V involved.

Comment: PSU OEM's must consider the 5V as a power "line." yet they didn't include the test procedure... or did they elsewhere? If so then its a "line". But true Load regulation would be more accurate except they probably ganged up all 5V lines in parallel hard wired to PSU. So load reg ought to be from a single line. as the PSU Zout and cable may be on same order of magnitude.  The 12V curve looked the same. oops